# Is there a way to parse this json using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Is there a way to parse this using jquery?

```
{"post_title":["car1","car2","car3"],"guid":["http:\/\/car1\/body\/fiat\/","http:\/\/car2\/body\/fiat\/","http:\/\/car3\/body\/fiat\/"]}

 $.getJSON($theUrl, function(data){
        var myData = [];
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
          console.log(item[0]);
          myData.push("<li><a href="+item+">" + item+ "</a></li>");
        });
```

PHP CODE:

```
$s = array();
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  $s['post_title'][] = get_the_title();
  $s['guid'][] = get_permalink();
endwhile; 
echo json_encode($s);
```

Can someone help me please!

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, but you're not closing off your `data` function.

Comment: It looks like you should be building your data differently.  [{"post_title": "car1", guid: "guid for car 1"}, {"post_title": "car2", "guid": "..."}].

Comment: I can't figure out how to display the link and the title, `item['post_title']` dosn't work, same for the guid.

Comment: Corbin how should I do that using php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should probably be building your data differently.

```
$s = array();
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  $s['post_title'][] = get_the_title();
  $s['guid'][] = get_permalink();
endwhile; 
echo json_encode($s);
```

Should likely be:

```
$s = array();
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $s[] = array(
        'post_title' => get_the_title(),
        'guid' => get_permalink(),
    );    
endwhile; 
echo json_encode($s);
```

Then your JS would look something like:

```
$.getJSON($theUrl, function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        //item.post_title
        //item.guid
    });
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help :).  Also, on a picky side note: I'm not sure if they're custom written, or part of some kind of forum or something, but the implied globals abuse in the_post, get_the_title and get_permalink kind of makes me cringe.  It makes no sense reading it.  the_post() somehow primes the next post to be read by two separate functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try parseJSON:

```
jQuery.parseJSON();
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does have [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Or you could just use 'JSON.parse()' with [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) as a fallback for browsers that don't natively support this.

Answer (score 1):

parseJSON() - http://jsfiddle.net/VHpLp/

Answer (score 0):

Ya, to parse JSON on the client/browser, use:

```
 var jsonObj = JSON.parse(yourJsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to parse the JSON string on the client-side, jQuery will work and the syntax would be:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

[API jQuery - jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

If you are trying to parse it on the server-side the syntax and tools would depend on what JSON library you are using. I am not familiar with PHP so I do not know what is available there.

**Side note** - make sure your JSON is properly formed before you worry about parsing.